# ESP and a metal cover (but not on every devboad) cover under which it hides

Tags: emc, esp32, device, metal, shield

This is regarding the metal cover on the ESP devboards, which covers, among others, the ESP itself, flash memory, etc.:

[image]

This topic has been discussed here before, and the reason for this cover is
mitigating the impact of EMI.

[ESP-12 (ESP8266) without the metal cover](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/484159/esp-12-esp8266-without-the-metal-cover)

The multitude of variants of ESP modules and devboards with them makes me dizzy. However, I noticed that this metal cover is not available on every PCB with ESP.

https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/1005005010891232.html
[image]

For example, this is a development board based on the ESP32-C3FN4 chip.

Modules with C3 were advertised as the successors to ESP8266. Devboards with C3 come in different variants, but the one without a metal cover surprised me. Moreover, some undertake the redesign of these tiles, also without using the cover.

[ESP32 devboard redesign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxU_Kw2de08&t=165s)

The information on the web that I found says only that the existence of this metal cover was to result from the need to meet the FCC requirements.

Applications for ESP32 in commercial devices are hard to find. Therefore, would it be acceptable not to use such a metal cover/shield in commercial projects (or hobby projects, but carried out with common sense), and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metal cover is an RF shield, and its purpose is to mitigate unwanted RF emissions such as harmonics and noise resulting from the contained circuit.

When you mass-produce a product that emits radio frequencies, you may or may not have an obligation to meet your country's requirements for which portion of the spectrum you transmit on, at what power, for what duration, and to what degree harmonics and noise are attenuated compared to the fundamental. In fact, even if you don't mass-produce anything, you can still be liable for building a device that interferes with other communications or broadcast. Obviously this varies by country.

In the US, the Federal Communications Commission (FCC) is the regulatory body that governs spectrum use and deals with the enforcement of compliance. When my company builds a product that receives and transmits on various bands, we must have our devices tested and verified, otherwise we could face legal action by affected users of the spectrum, or from the FCC itself.

That said, we frequently work on prototypes and defective units that don't have RF shields, or we intentionally remove them in order to diagnose and work on the product. Such use tends to be limited, both in duration and geographic area (we only test in one location). In other words, we don't leave non-shielded devices on for long times, nor do we ship products out that lack necessary shields.

It's worth considering, too, that depending on the operating mode of the circuit, the shield might not be necessary. For example, at lower transmit powers, or with certain modulation schemes, harmonics and noise are within acceptable limits. But when the device transmits over a certain power level, or in certain modes, these unwanted emissions can be over allowed limits, thus requiring the shield to help keep them in check.

My advice is, for any commercial project, to absolutely go through the necessary testing to ensure you're not breaking any laws. You can work with many companies that have testing facilities (anechoic RF chambers and measurement equipment) to check where your product stands before submitting to an official verification.

For hobby projects, it's a little more vague. You're may technically never be allowed to interfere or jam signals (again, depending on where you are in the world), but if you aren't actually causing any problems that would result in the agency tracking down the source of the interference, a one-off project that doesn't operate continuously is hardly a concern.

Think about it this way: If you live close to other people and your device causes something of theirs to behave oddly (stereo noise, TV interference, mobile phone signal loss, etc.) it could escalate to a bad situation, ranging anywhere from a simple complaint to legal action.

It is possible that the devices you are purchasing have shields based on whether or not they meet the requirements of the market in which they are sold. It could be that they are close to the threshold, and thus some modules do not need the shield, while others do. It's also possible that they are produced not in accordance with regulations, or are being imported/exported without regard for those sorts of things. Ultimately, it is up to you to check if you need to be compliant, especially in a commercial sense.

Comment: Well, I think I have an explanation why most hobby projects are based on ready-made ESP boards with metal covers. I assume that the finished ESP module boards have passed the tests before being released to the market. However, if we made a project in which we put a ready-made ESP module together with a metal cover, would we have to acquire additional permissions beyond those already available in the ESP module we use?

Comment: @Karlsson Not necessarily. If the rest of your project isn't adding any additional radio emissions, you may be just fine. Think about computer monitors, for example, that use an external "wall wart" power supply. It is a means for the monitor manufacturer to not have to undergo the safety testing required for having AC mains in their product. If your radio component is already tested/certified, you may be "good to go." Still, I'd have your final design checked by a (less-expensive) company if you're making it commercially. If all looks well, you shouldn't need to then pass government regs.

Comment: "RF emissions such as harmonics and noise resulting from the contained circuit" Most of these IC are duplex, I believe. And so most often it's the other way around - the shielding is there to improve radiated susceptibility by blocking outside EMI for reaching the late stages in the RX RF path. Whereas it is unlikely that a TX RF path is a significant source of EMI before the signal reaches the PA. That being said, modern RFIC often have integrated PA on-chip.

Answer (score 2):

> Therefore, would it be acceptable not to use such a metal cover/shield in commercial projects (or hobby projects, but carried out with common sense), and if so, why?

The only thing that matters here is if the RFIC vendor is serious and what claims of compliance they are making. FCC compliance is required for North America, CE compliance is required for Europe. The rest of the world often (but not always) require compliance with either FCC and/or CE. Additionally, product compliance testing is required for things like Bluetooth.

I don't know these parts and couldn't find the CE declaration of conformity for this specific part, but just as an example here's one for one of its siblings: [ESP32-WROVER-E & ESP32-WROVER-IE CE Certification](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/ESP32-WROVER-E%20%26%20ESP32-WROVER-IE%20CE%20Certification.pdf). The important parts being compliance to EN 300 328 (2.4GHz radio compliance) and EN 301 489-1 (general EMC). A serious vendor will also share test rapports against these standards - I don't recognize any of the companies in this document. Notably, there doesn't even exist any "certification" for EN ETSI standards, only FCC has an actual certification process (with separate certification for Canada etc).

Also, parts sold by Aliexpress and similar shady vendors do not necessarily conform to neither CE nor FCC. For example they could have been developed for the Chinese internal market which has yet another set of different rules.

Anyway - these are the guarantees made by the manufacturer. If you modify their product in any way, like removing the shielding, the guarantees no longer apply. If you use antennas other than those approved by the manufacturer, the guarantees no longer apply. Including product certifications like Bluetooth SIG etc turning invalid.

But you pretty much have to do your own CE and/or FCC marking regardless, due to the fact that it is impossible to reason as "my voltage supply to the RF module doesn't affect EMC". It *always* has a very big impact on EMC.

Also when it comes to RF, it doesn't really matter if the product is commercial or hobbyist, because a hobbyist RF product could still cause illegal interference with commercial ones.

Regarding the metal shielding, that's a design choice by the RF designers. One always tries to make an EMC compliant product without the need of shielding, but in case it isn't possible you might end up with a shield. This also depends on area of application - mainstream EMC requirements are actually not that hard to fulfill.